# Opto-coupler high vs low CTR

Tags: current, opto-isolator, switching, delay

I want to understand how the CTR of an opto-coupler is linked with its other parameters, for example its switching speed or time delay between input and output or any other parameter.

I am using opto-couplers to switch digital signals.

For example if I have 2 different opto-couplers, first one has just 10% CTR (min) value while the second one has 1000% CTR (min) values.

So when an opto-coupler has 1000% CTR then what parameter would be compromised in it with respect to another opto-coupler that has just 10% CTR value?

Mainly I am comparing [HCPL-0530](http://www.suzushoweb.com/pdf_file/7310000000018.pdf) and [HCPL-6751](https://www.datasheet.live/index.php?title=Special:PdfViewer&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpdf.datasheet.live%2F34aa0422%2Fagilent.com%2FHCPL-6751.pdf).

Edit:

Let me explain me question more. First ignore the above two opto-couplers as I can now understand that they are of different types and cannot be compared as such.

Let us say we have two similar type of opto's from same manufacturer and in the same product category/family, say both have simple phototransistor at the output stage and simple LED at input. One of them has higher CTR, say 80% while the other has lower than that say 10% only. What I wanted to understand is that given this much info can I say something about the relative values of some other parameter of these Opto's? Possibly if an opto has higher CTR then its some other parameter will be relatively lower compared to another opto which has lower CTR. So is there any other parameter whose value goes seesaw with CTR 
value?

Comment: Please note that the CTR is measured at a specific forward current, and that the CTR changes when the forward current changes. These two devices are designed for very different forward currents, and are not comparable.

Comment: I am interested to know that if an opto has very high CTR then what parameter will be compromised in it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between optoisolator output styles?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/187706/what-are-the-differences-between-optoisolator-output-styles)