# Choose appropriate opto-isolator for 230 Vac zero-cross detection circuit

Tags: led, opto-isolator, triac, zero-crossing, full-bridge

I struggle to understand the datasheet for opto-isolators. I am making a 230 Vac circuit with a full-bridge rectifier. What should I look for when choosing an appropriate opto-isolator?

I've been looking at the [FOD817](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/fod814-d.pdf). The output will go to a microcontroller input and further to a triac trigger. The overall goal is to sync my dimmer signal with a 230 Vac sine wave.

[image: Circuit with resistance and full bridge rectifier]

Comment: The MOC30xx series includes some devices with zero-cross detection and those with zero-cross detection are designed to directly trigger a triac for you. (I use them with a pair of SCRs instead, because I very much prefer a pair of SCRs over a TRIAC.) But there's also the AMC23C10, for example. And if you just google up "zero cross detector IC" you should find lots of hits. Make your own choices, from there, about what is more readily available to you (or meets your price objectives.)

Comment: Also see [What are the differences between optoisolator output styles?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/187706/29811)